# I want to import Dictionary but it has problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.6, python-3.5

I am trying to import dictionary in a python file. My code is as below:

```py
from gensim.corpora
import Dictionary
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary([token_list])
dictionary.token2id
```

This is not working fine and I am getting following error:

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-3a3520a7e6ae> in <module>
----> 1 dictionary = corpora.Dictionary([token_list])
     2 dictionary.token2id

NameError: name 'corpora' is not defined
```

I have already installed this library. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not defined or imported anzthing named `corpora`. what you did was import `Dictionary` from `gensim.corpora`. By using

```
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
```

You can use `Dictionary` like this:

```
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
dictionary = Dictionary([token_list])
dictionary.token2id
```